# How to know when client stops ping-ing Java server?

Tags: java, servlets, client-server, embedded-jetty

I've decided to have my client "ping" the server periodically so that I know the client is still alive. I'm using a Jetty server embedded in a Java application and I have a HttpServlet to handle the clients requests.

On the server side, how do I know when the client hasn't "pinged" (sent a request) in a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on srini.venigalla's answer, you could use something like this as a starting point.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class PingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long EXPIRATION_MILLIS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30);

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Long> sessionIdToLastPingTime = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public void init() {
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                scanForExpiredSessions();
            }
        }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void scanForExpiredSessions() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : sessionIdToLastPingTime.entrySet()) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                return;
            }

            final String sessionId = entry.getKey();
            final Long lastPing = entry.getValue();
            if (lastPing == null) {
                // entry was removed from the map by another thread
                continue;
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastPing + EXPIRATION_MILLIS) {
                sessionIdToLastPingTime.remove(sessionId);
                try {
                    expireSession(sessionId);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // production code should use a logger
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void expireSession(String sessionId) {
        // production code should use a logger
        System.out.println("client stopped pinging for session " + sessionId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String sessionId = req.getSession().getId();
        sessionIdToLastPingTime.put(sessionId, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        executor.shutdownNow();

        try {
            // this is optional, but may prevent Tomcat from reporting the webapp as a memory-leaker
            executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {                                                                          
            // production code should use a logger
            System.out.println("interrupted while waiting for executor to shut down");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is just what I was looking for. Your a boss :D.  I will adapt this implementation method to my current code.

Comment: You're welcome. Before you go too far down this path, consider whether an HttpSessionListener with a short session timeout meets your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Identify the client by its sessionID, and keep track of the last ping. Scan all last pings periodically and find those who have not pinged in N minutes.

Comment: You might use a ConcurrentHashMap to associate each ping time with the corresponding session id. You might use a ScheduledExecutorService to trigger the scan. Don't forget to remove the map entry when the session expires.

Comment: Also, look out for this gotcha: when iterating over the entries of a ConcurrentMap, entry.getValue() might return null if the entry was removed by another thread.

Comment: @dnault So I should have the servlet update the ConcurrentHashMap which resides in a different thread? The thread will then safely scan the hash map removing entries that have gone cold. Let me know if I understood you right, I will do a search on the ConcurrentHashMap :)

Answer (score 0):

The trivial case:

1. Tell the client to ping every N seconds
2. Keep a timestamp of when the last time the client pinged, updating the timestamp after each client ping
3. If this timestamp is significantly greater than N seconds, the client has stopped pinging (at least for now)

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can use the java Date class to store when the last time was you received a ping.

```
long lastRecv = System.getTimeMillis();
```

In another loop (perhaps another thread that periodically checks an array of all known clients), you would check the lastRecv timecode and compare it to right now.

```
if( date.getTime() - lastRecv > TIMEOUT_IN_MS )
    // Handle user timing out
```

Every time a new ping is recevied just update the lastRecv time to the new current time.  You will know when a user has timed out because you have some preset threshold (such as TIMEOUT_IN_MS) that is less than the last time you saw a ping come in.

Obviously you will have to modify the example code I gave here to reflect the number of clients, your threading model, and data model, but I think it gets across the idea well enough.

Comment: Prefer System.currentTimeMillis() over new Date().getTime(). Store the result in a long, not an int.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So the array of known clients and their lastRecv times are located in another thread. How does the servlet update the array?

Comment: Would I have to dive into cross-thread calls and locking, so that the thread doesn't check the time while I'm updating it?

Comment: You can if you want super up-to-date values, but I wouldn't worry too much.  If anything, it just means that the server doesn't know the client disconnected until the next time it checks if you update it right as you read it.  If this is a concern then you would have to use some kind of locking model.  Also, dnault's suggestion to use a long and to use System.getTimeMillis() is correct.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have updated my examples to include dnault's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an HttpSessionListener with a short session timeout?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html